# DDL Statements in DBMS_JOB

Tags: oracle, ddl, dbms-job

I am trying to schedule a job using DBMS_JOB (I can't use DBMS_SCHEDULER for security reasons), which uses a DDL statement.

```
DECLARE
job_num NUMBER;
BEGIN
DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT(job => job_num,
what => 'BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ''CREATE TABLE temp1 (ID NUMBER)''; END;'
);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('JobID'||job_num);
DBMS_JOB.RUN(job_num);
END;
/
```

It fails to execute giving me an error message :

> ORA-12011: execution of 1 jobs failed
>   ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_IJOB", line 548
>   ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_JOB", line 278
>   ORA-06512: at line 8

On removing the **DBMS_JOB.RUN()** statement from inside the anonymous block, I am able to at least create (and save) the job. When I check the job, it has saved this as the  **code to execute**
    BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE temp1 (id NUMBER) '; END;

If I execute it standalone, it obviously executes. The only time it fails it when I try to execute the entire thing through the call to DBMS_JOB.RUN().

Is there a restriction on using DDL statements as a parameter in DBMS_JOB? I can't find any pointer in documentation for this.

Comment: I have never heard of the error message "always"...

Comment: Added the error message I get "always"

Comment: Can you expand on the security reasons that prevent you from using DBMS_Scheduler? Also, have you looked at using global temporary tables? Seeing a table called TEMP being created is a bit of a red flag.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. It worked for me (tested in 11gR2), and the job created the table "TEMP" as expected.

Comment: +1 to Aldridge's comment - creating tables on-the-fly is usually a sign of a poor system design.

Comment: The actual table name, which I have to create is not called "TEMP". I just used it for posting this question here. Also, my actual intent is to create a temporary table only, and not a table. I don't have much flexibility, since I am modifying some section of an application and "unwillingly" have to go through this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While echoing the sentiments of the other commenters-- creating tables on the fly is a red flag that often indicates that you really ought to be using global temporary tables-- a couple of questions.

1. Is there a reason that you need the `DBMS_JOB.RUN` call?  Your call to `DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT` is telling Oracle to run the job asynchronously as soon as the parent transaction commits.  So, normally, you'd call `DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT` and then just `COMMIT'.
2. Does the user that is submitting job have the `CREATE TABLE` privilege granted directly?  My guess is that the user only has the `CREATE TABLE` privilege granted via a role.  That would allow you to run the anonymous PL/SQL block interactively but not in a job.  If so, you'll need the DBA to grant you the `CREATE TABLE` privilege directly, not via a role.
3. When a job fails, an entry is written to the alert log with the error message.  Can you (or, more likely, the DBA) get the error message and the error stack from the alert log and post it here (assuming it is something other than the privileges issue from #2).

Comment: Thanks Justin. This helps a lot. I will check with DBA for that privileges for create table first!